# Reference a website within Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way that I can reference a given website without physically loading it? For example, if I wanted to search Yahoo's front page for the text “Bananas”…

```
var site = (location.href ="http://yahoo.com");
var arraycontainsturtles = (site.indexOf("Bananas") > -1);
window.prompt(arraycontainsturtles)
```

This will load yahoo, and then pop up with a prompt saying true or false. How would I acquire this behavior without physically loading Yahoo, and instead just having the prompt say true or false?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code won't do what you say it does.

Comment: You can make an AJAX request to that site but that requires either a) that site _allows_ you to make the request or b) you are on the same domain. This is because of the same origin policy.

Comment: I believe security sandboxing issues make your proposal impossible. I have heard of some very good `node.js` implementations that do this. See `www.stylifyme.com`

Comment: You could also have a 0x0 (or 1x1) iframe in which you can load the site.

Comment: You have to download data if you want to search thru it

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) .   For example, you could query using [PhantomJS](https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/ServiceIntegration) to this service.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to literally search through a search engine, I just meant search the text of a webpage. And I used Yahoo as the example, which was stupid on my part.

Comment: YQL is not restricted to Yahoo services, you can query every URL on the web as JSONP.

Comment: Well, for searching text of a page, PhamtomJS is just about the best thing you could use IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a ajax get request to your url and return to content as json or somthing similar. This is how you can do it in using jquery.

```
$.get('www.yourwebsite.com?searchParam=banana', function(data) {
   // data will contain the search results for your keyword banana
});
```

**assume** : You need to have a script written in www.yourwebsite.com to get the value pass through searchParam (in this case banana) and search content from the db and return.

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not load any external website. You are basically creating a string that you are searching through - that is why a `site.indexOf("yahoo");` is `true`, but `site.indexOf("bananas");` is `false`.

There are various APIs you can use for a number of search engines, which allow you to retrieve search results in [often] XML format. This will need to be done using a server-side language such as PHP, however.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't literally mean I wanted to search Yahoo's search engine, I just meant searching within the website. It was probably a bad example site to use.

Comment: Because of same-origin policy, you can't do this with JavaScript, however, you will again have better success using a server-side language

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially looking at a basic form of HTML scraping functionality. This post lists out the some of the options available for implementing the functionality - [Options for HTML scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)

Comment: As his question refers specifically to JavaScript perhaps you could also mention specifically some JavaScript libraries out there that he could use? Also, as others mention, using JavaScript will suffer from same origin policy issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) to get text content from a page(by making an AJAX request) and then search for the text.

```
var url='http://google.com';
$.get('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22'+encodeURI(url)+"%22", function(resp){
    var text = $(resp).text(); // text from url
    console.log( text.search('google') ); // search for "google"
});
```

Here's an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EPqaS/).